# How to make a table left outer join of multiple tables

Tags: sql, join

I am need to join a main table with two feed tables.Table data below:

MainTable

[image]

FeedTable

[image]

Query I am running is left inner join

```
Select ID, MT.ColumnA, FT1.ColumnA, FT1.ColumnB, FT2.ColumnA, FT2.ColumnC, FT3.ColumnA, FT3.ColumnD
from MainTable MT
Left Join FeedTable FTI1 on FT1.fk1 = MT.key
Left Join FeedTable FT2 on FT2.fk2 = MT.key
Left Join FeedTable FT3 on FT3.fk3 = MT.key
```

The output I get is :

[image]

The Output I want to get is :

[image]

I am assuming left outer join isn't the way to go about this or am I doing the join wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the tables in the wrong order.  The `FeedTable` should be first:

```
Select ft.*, mt1.key as cola, mt2.key as colb, mt3.key colc
from FeedTable ft left join
     MainTable mt1
     on ft.fk1 = mt1.key left join
     MainTable mt2
     on ft.fk2 = mt2.key left join
     MainTable mt2
     on ft.fk3 = mt3.key;
```